# popen sql string issue

Tags: python, string, postgresql, popen

Using Popen to run a PostgreSQL query.  This works:

```
maxId = 10

psql = "psql -d db -U user -t -c 'select id, experiment_id from results where id > " + maxId + "'"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'me@server', psql],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
```

When I add a like clause, it fails:

```
psql = "psql -d db -U user -t -c 'select id, experiment_id from results where status like '%Completed%' and id > " + maxId + "'"

['ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"\n', 'LINE 1: ...t_id" from results where status like %Completed...\n', '                                                             ^\n']
```

I've tried several quotation alternatives but can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

TD

UPDATE:
Was finally able to preserve the double-quoted column names across the call to psql as well as the original issue of passing a like clause in single quotes. Solution below:

Found the hint here: [Keeping double quotes when passing string to popen in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689738/keeping-double-quotes-when-passing-string-to-popen-in-c)

```
psqlcmd = 'psql -U choa -d iondb -t -c ' 
sql = "\"select id, experiment_id, \\\"resultsName\\\" from rundb_results where status like '%Completed%' and id > 5;\""

print(psqlcmd)
print(sql)

ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'me@server', psqlcmd, sql],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this and I managed to do it on the shell, but doing it through Python was a mess. I'll show my findings incase it helps you solve your problem.

Notice that the difference is the double quotes on the outside of your select statement.

You need to either escape a set of your single quotes, or change to double quotes and escape a set of double quotes.

```
[root@server tmp]# /opt/rh/postgresql/bin/psql -d database -U user -c 'select * from control where option_name like '%MANAGE%';'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: select * from control where option_name like %MANAGE%;
                                                     ^


[root@server tmp]# /opt/rh/postgresql/bin/psql -d database -U user -c "select * from control where option_name like '%MANAGE%';"
 option_name  | status 
--------------+--------
 MANAGE_NTPD  | false
 MANAGE_DHCP4 | false
 MANAGE_DHCP6 | false
 MANAGE_NAMED | false
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks - a quoting issue to be sure but so far can't get it right.  Maybe python is further editing the string in some way.

Comment: Yeah I've had the same problem too in the past. Especially when you split your psql prefix into a string on its own and then allow that to be formatted with different sql statements, and then try to plug all of this into subprocess command where it wants you to split the string... (nightmare)... and you're also trying to do this over ssh..? /wrists

Comment: Just gonna give you a tip, you should look into using psycopg2. It's easier to use and it's better than running commands on the command line using the psql tool

Comment: I'll look into it.  This is vendor provided machine and we cannot install any software or run processes locally...  hence the ssh